# Dividing an input into diffferent lists by the lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to divide a multi-lined input into different lists by the lines. Is there a method for that?

For example:

```
#The input:
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0

#What I request:
column1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] #the first line as a list
column2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1] # the second line as a a list
.
. #so goes on
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want a list of lists, not individual variables for each row.  If you do it this way, once `output` is built, you can call any row by index, such as `output[2]`, etc

```
s ='''0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0'''

s  = s.split('\n')

output = [list(map(int,x.split())) for x in s]
```

Output

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a method. This line is pretty much the standard:

```
first_line = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

**Breakdown**:

1. First, `input()` takes one line of input from input stream i.e. "0 0 0 0 0".
2. `split` method breaks it by `' '` (space) which results in `["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]`
3. Then `map` function is used to convert every `character` to `integer` i.e. from `"0"` to `0`.

---

If you want to process all input lines regardless of the input length, then you can use `fileinput.input()`. Here's a sample code:

```
import fileinput
input_grid = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in fileinput.input()]
```

**input_grid:**

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific please (I'm pretty new to this)? About the map and the int parameter part especailly

Comment: Sure, `map` is a function that takes  a function and a sequence as parameters and transform each value from sequence using the input parameter function which happens to be `int` in this case. So, it converts every `string` object to `int` object.

Comment: Yeah, I was just going to ask that. What about the other lines? I was able to get the first line but can't reach to the others

Comment: @Chris Yeah, but you can always use loops.

Comment: @AniketTiratkar I believe being able to parse each line was part of his original question

Comment: @Chris Sorry if I missed that. I am going to update my answer to satisfy that requirement. :)

Comment: @Chris I updated my answer, please check if it is what it should be.